# Does [Pure] have any implications other than "no visible side-effects" to Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, code-contracts, purely-functional

The [PureAttribute documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Indicates that a type or method is pure, that is, it does not make any visible state changes

1. Is this the *only* requirement of a Pure function under in Microsoft Code Contracts?
2. And; does this model assume that Exceptions are results  (as opposed to side-effects)?

I ask because, in a more general context, [a pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) *also* implies that the output is only dependent upon the input; ie. it cannot be the result of I/O or a stochastic function.

One might also argue that a pure function always yields a value to the outer expression, possibly in opposition to Exceptions.

If [Pure] is indeed limited to the less restrictive form, is there an equivalent of a "[FunctionalPure]"?

Comment: Related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335245/why-is-catching-an-exception-non-pure-but-throwing-an-exception-is-pure

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks - that's a very good read. I hadn't thought about it in terms of that deterministic (or lack of) nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static analyser assumes that calling the same pure function with the same arguments twice in a row produces the same result.

Given

```
[Pure]
public delegate int F(int i);

public class A
{
  public void f(F f)
  {
    var i = f(1);
    Contract.Assert(i == f(1));
  }
}
```

a warning is generated: "Suggested assumption: Assumption can be proven: Consider changing it into an assert."

So for instance `DateTime.Now` must not be annoted with the `Pure` attribute.

As for exceptions, there doesn't seem to be anything disallowing them, nor for requiring them to be thrown consistently. In general, there cannot be. You can always get an `OutOfMemoryException` for pretty much any code, even a pure function with the same arguments that previously succeeded.