# Robust haskell without errors

Tags: haskell, robustness

I'm currently learning Haskell. One of the motivations why I picked this language was to write software with a very high degree of robustness, i.e. functions that is fully defined, mathematically deterministic and never crash or produce errors. I don't mean failure caused by predicates of the system ("system out of memory", "computer on fire" etc), those are not interesting and can simply crash the entire process. I also don't mean errornous behaviour caused by invalid declarations (`pi = 4`).

Instead I refer to errors caused by erroneous states which I want to remove by making those states unrepresentable and non-compilable (in some functions) via strict static typing. In my mind I called these functions "pure" and figured that the strong type system would allow me to accomplish this. However Haskell does not define "pure" in this way and allow programs to crash via `error` in any context.

[Why is catching an exception non-pure, but throwing an exception is pure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335245/why-is-catching-an-exception-non-pure-but-throwing-an-exception-is-pure)

This is completely acceptable and not strange at all. The disappointing thing however is that Haskell does not appear to provide some functionality to forbid function definitions that could lead to branches using `error`.

Here's a contrived example why I find this disappointing:

```
module Main where
import Data.Maybe

data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Orange Int | Peach
    deriving(Show)

readFruit :: String -> Maybe Fruit
readFruit x =
    case x of
         "apple" -> Just Apple
         "banana" -> Just Banana
         "orange" -> Just (Orange 4)
         "peach" -> Just Peach
         _ -> Nothing

showFruit :: Fruit -> String
showFruit Apple = "An apple"
showFruit Banana = "A Banana"
showFruit (Orange x) = show x ++ " oranges"

printFruit :: Maybe Fruit -> String
printFruit x = showFruit $ fromJust x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let fruit = readFruit line
    putStrLn $ printFruit fruit
    main
```

Let's say that I'm paranoid that the pure functions `readFruit` and `printFruit` really doesn't fail due to unhanded states. You could imagine that the code is for launching a rocket full of astronauts which in an absolutely critical routine needs to serialize and unserialize fruit values.

The first danger is naturally that we made a mistake in our pattern matching as this gives us the dreaded erroneous states that can't be handled. Thankfully Haskell provides built in ways to prevent those, we simply compile our program with  `-Wall` which includes `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` and AHA:

```
src/Main.hs:17:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘showFruit’: Patterns not matched: Peach
```

We forgot to serialize Peach fruits and `showFruit` would have thrown an error. That's an easy fix, we simply add:

```
showFruit Peach = "A peach"
```

The program now compiles without warnings, danger averted! We launch the rocket but suddenly the program crashes with:

```
Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

The rocket is doomed and hits the ocean caused by the following faulty line:

```
printFruit x = showFruit $ fromJust x
```

Essentially `fromJust` has a branch where it raises an `Error` so we didn't even want the program to compile if we tried to use it since `printFruit` absolutely had to be "super" pure. We could have fixed that for example by replacing the line with:

```
printFruit x = maybe "Unknown fruit!" (\y -> showFruit y) x
```

I find it strange that Haskell decides to implement strict typing and incomplete pattern detection, all in the nobel pursuit of preventing invalid states from being representable but falls just in front of the finish line by not giving programmers a way to detect branches to `error` when they are not allowed. In a sense this makes Haskell less robust then Java which forces you to declare the exceptions your functions are allowed to raise.

The most trivial way to implement this would be to simply undefined `error` in some way, locally for a function and any function used by its equation via some form of associated declaration. However this does not appear to be possible.

[The wiki page about errors vs exceptions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Extended_Static_Checking) mentions an extension called "Extended Static Checking" for this purpose via contracts but it just leads to a broken link.

It basically boils down to: How do I get the program above to not compile because it uses `fromJust`? All ideas, suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Comment: (1) I believe [these are the papers you are looking for](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/verify/index.htm). (2) Note that `printFruit` is unnecessary. If an user wants to display a `Maybe Fruit` she can use `fmap showFruit` and then unwrap the `Maybe` in a sensible way. That of course does not answer your question (it would be good to keep users away from `fromJust` as well!), so carry on :)

Comment: I'd love Haskell to have a sort of totality checker. I'd even be satisfied with a no-exception checker checking for non exhaustiveness and use of partial functions, but not checking for infinite loops. I'd also like to raise these kind of warnings into errors, so that I can not easily overlook them. This probably would not require a large amount of effort to implement in GHC.

Comment: Have you looked at Idris? It might be the language you want.

Comment: See also [`hlint`](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I wanted was a level of totality checking that Haskell unfortunately does not provide (yet?).

Alternatively I want dependent types (e.g. [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/)), or a static verifier (e.g. [Liquid Haskell](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell)) or syntax lint detection (e.g. [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/)).

I'm really looking into Idris now, it seems like an amazing language. Here's a [talk by the founder of Idris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkIlW797JN8) that I can recommend watching.

Credits for these answers goes to @duplode, @chi, @user3237465 and @luqui.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell allows arbitrary general recursion, so it's not as though all Haskell programs would necessarily be total, if only `error` in its various forms were removed. That is, you could just define `error a = error a` to take care of any case you don't want to handle anyways. A runtime error is just more helpful than an infinite loop.

You should not think of `error` as similar to a garden-variety Java exception. `error` is an assertion failure representing a programming error, and a function like `fromJust` which can call `error` is an assertion. You should not attempt to catch the exception produced by `error` except in special cases like a server that must continue to run even when the handler for a request encounters a programming error.

Comment: I would not say that the terminology "assertion" is obvious in this case as this is usually associated with a documentation/debug construct that can safely be removed for performance reasons in other languages and has no implication on the functional logic itself of the program. Rather, an error in Haskell is more similar to a dynamic cast error in other languages. When arbitrary functions can throw them you're walking a minefield if you're writing robust software and not even the compiler can help you. One wrong API call and you're doomed.

Comment: @hanneslandeholm, you should consider languages like Coq and Agda. Haskell is not designed for what you want, although it offers some good tools for writing safe and correct code. No one has managed, thus far, to write a dependently typed, strongly normalizing language that is also suitable for most practical programming. Haskell is a compromise.

Comment: @dfeuer, why is Idris not suitable for practical programming? It has proper effects system, compiles to C, performs various optimizations, has a lof of syntactic sugar, proper type holes (well, Agda's are better), tactics and other quite practical stuff. Compare this to super ugly monad transformers and the institute of [hasochism](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf). A practical dependently typed programming language already exists, it just has pure ecosystem.

Comment: @user3237465, to my mind, Idris feels a bit more like a bucket of bolts than a tool kit. Trying to prove non-trivial theorems in it is extremely hard, and the lead developer doesn't seem to care too much about that application. Laziness is pretty much critical when trying to write formally verified, efficient data structures without going batty. But Idris's automatic delay/force insertions play very badly with proofs. Maybe Idris will be good some day, but it's not yet.

Comment: @dfeuer, I agree, that Idris is not very good proof assistant (the underlying theory doesn't contain metavariables, emacs mode is very clunky, no unicode and mixfix operators and so on), but it's still a great *programming* language.

Comment: @user3237465, it also has about four features each of which is almost, but not quite, a module system. And for practical programming, it has nothing to match Haskell's classes.

Comment: @dfeuer, in tutorials (mostly about effects), that I read, Idris' type classes were pretty good both in theory (because they are first-class) and in practice (because they work). But I've never used them, so I don't know much (I guess they have the same problems as Agda's instance arguments). I would ask for some elaborations on your statement, but this discussion is irrelevant, so I shouldn't.

Comment: @user3237465, once you've written Van Laarhoven lenses in Idris, you will find them fairly hard to use. Once you've defined `VerifiedMonoid` in terms of `VerifiedSemigroup` and `Monoid`, you will find it very hard to use it. It's easy to pooh-pooh Haskell's global instance coherence until you see how hard life gets without it and the resolution approach it enables. May I ask why it's good to have metavariables in the underlying theory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86574/discussion-between-user3237465-and-dfeuer).

Answer (score 1):

Your main complaint is about `fromJust`, but given it is fundamentally against what your goals are, why are you using it?

Remember that the biggest reason for `error` is that not everything can be defined in a way that the type system can guarantee, so having a "This can't happen, trust me" makes sense. `fromJust` comes from this mindset of "sometimes I know better than the compiler". If you don't agree with that mindset don't use it. Alternatively don't abuse it like this example does.

EDIT:

To expand on my point, think of how you would implement what you are asking for (warnings on using partial functions). Where would the warning apply in the following code?

```
a = fromJust $ Just 1
b = Just 2
c = fromJust $ c
d = fromJust
e = d $ Just 3
f = d b
```

All of these are statically not partial after all. (Sorry if this next one's syntax is off, it is late)

```
g x = fromJust x + 1
h x = g x + 1
i = h $ Just 3
j = h $ Nothing
k x y = if x > 0 then fromJust y else x
l = k 1 $ Just 2
m = k (-1) $ Just 3
n = k (-1) $ Nothing
```

`i` here is again safe, but `j` is not. Which method should return the warning? What do we do when some or all of these methods are defined outside of our function. What do you do in the case of `k` where it is conditionally partial? Should some or all of these functions fail?

By making the compiler make this call you are conflating a lot of complicated problems. Especially when you consider that careful library selection avoids it.

In either case the solution IMO to these kinds of problems is to use a tool after or during compilation to look for problems rather than modifying the compiler. Such a tool can more easily understand "your code" vs "their code" and better determine where best to warn you upon inappropriate use. You could also tune it without having to add a bunch of annotations to your source file to avoid false positives. I don't know a tool offhand or I would suggest one.

Comment: You're approaching my question from the wrong angle. The example is contrived to highlight how a programmer can introduce an error path by mistake. The mistake can also be more subtle like allowing a branch where divide by zero is possible. The "well, just don't make mistakes" assumption makes the type system itself largely pointless. Also you're admitting yourself that the function is more dangerous, wouldn't it be useful if calls to such dangerous functions could somehow be prevented by the compiler?

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: I will expand my answer, but this isn't a case of "don't make mistakes" it is "don't use tools that don't agree with your paradigm". If `fromJust` and its ilk could break guarentees then your argument would have merit, but `_|_` is always something that can creep up.

Comment: I recently started working on a 7 million line codebase (not in Haskell), so I put on that lens when reading OP's question.  "Don't use X" isn't really an acceptable solution in such a huge place.  It would be essential to have a tool check for such cases.  FWIW [`hlint`](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) will do this if I remember right.

Comment: @luqui: hlint is what I am trying to say *should* be the solution. The compiler need not and likely should not be the solution for every engineering problem.